# 1 dimensional chart in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, charts, flash-builder, timeline

I want a bubble chart that just shows items along a straight line. So I'd like the horizontal axis to essentially not exist.  I have it working right now with the yField assigned to a field that happens to always be '1' on my test dataset.. but this is not going to be the case in general, so I need some way to restrict the y-axis... preferably without needing to go back to my model and parse through all my data to add a dummy value '1' on each entry.

Unfortunately setting min/max values just cuts off anything above or below rather than restricting entries.

I set computedMin and Maximum (no idea what they are and the docs don't really explain) but it didn't seem to restrict the data in any way.

Any way to achieve this?

Comment: every [math exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/) user's brain is steaming

Comment: Why would you use a bubble chart if you're only showing one value?  Bar chart would be more appropriate.

Comment: i need it to be a series of circles whose size is based on a value and x-position is based on time.. bubble chart seemed best way to do it since they have that built in already. you're right bar chart has the correct number of variables, perhaps i could frankenstein them together, but i'm working on a pretty tight timeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try extending BubbleChart to BuubleChartExt and override updateDisplayList method to reposition your bubbles.
You can have a look at source of existing updateDisplaylist if you have FlexBuilder3 professional license. Source code info [here](http://blogs.adobe.com/pdehaan/2008/03/checking_out_the_source_code_f.html). you just need to change positioning info.